Visual Studio Code crashes when started from command line - profile specific
When I try to start Visual Studio Code (v 1.89.0) from the command line, via
code or open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app the app icon bounces and then the app crashes. Error below.
I've tried reinstalling the app. And completely removing all user settings:
#!/bin/sh
rm -fvr ~/Library/Preferences/com.microsoft.VSCode.plist
rm -fvr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode
rm -fvr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.VSCode.ShipIt/
rm -fvr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/
rm -fvr ~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.microsoft.VSCode.savedState/
rm -fvr ~/.vscode/

Unfortunately nothing seems to help. Codium has the same problem.
Opening the application by clicking on it in the GUI works fine.
Opening the application from the command line in a different user profile also works fine. --> This makes me believe there is something in my profile messing with the application. But... I've deleted all Visual Studio Code user setting I even ran find ~/Library -iname "*vscode*" -exec rm -rfv {} \;.
Any suggestions are welcome.
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Electron [8177]
Path:                  /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
Identifier:            com.microsoft.VSCode
Version:               1.89.0 (1.89.0)
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2024-05-06 13:05:43.2465 +0200
OS Version:            macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        A768D014-9292-A323-443D-D16A2FB1D8CC

Sleep/Wake UUID:       69BF273A-BFD7-4318-85D6-10436589C244

Time Awake Since Boot: 4200 seconds
Time Since Wake:       452 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x000000010df8035c

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 5 Trace/BPT trap: 5
Terminating Process:   exc handler [8177]

Visual Studio Code version
Version: 1.89.0
Commit: b58957e67ee1e712cebf466b995adf4c5307b2bd
Date: 2024-05-01T02:10:13.496Z (5 days ago)
Electron: 28.2.8
ElectronBuildId: 27744544
Chromium: 120.0.6099.291
Node.js: 18.18.2
V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 23.4.0

Solved
Turns out I had the following line in my .zshrc profile
export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1

Removing the line solved the issues.

Did you logout or even reboot after clearing out ~/Library?

To be clear: I did completely empty ~/Library. Only used the commands in my post. But yes, I did reboot (several times).
